# Integrating Gaussian Curvature

Tags: geometry

$\underline{Question}$

Let the surface $S$ be given by: $$\mathbf{x}(u,v) = \begin{pmatrix}\cosh (u)\cos(v)\\
\cosh(u)\sin (v)\\
u\end{pmatrix} \quad -\infty < u < \infty, \,\, 0<v<2\pi,$$

write down the area form of $S$ and show that  the total area is infinite but the integrated Gauss curvature $\int_S K = - 4\pi$

$\underline{Attempt}$

So I calculate $d\mathbf{x}= \mathbf{x}_udu +\mathbf{x}_vdv$ and it turns out that $\mathbf{x}_u$ and $\mathbf{x}_v$ are orthogonal so I normalise them and take: $$\mathbf{e}_1=\mathbf{x}_u/|\mathbf{x}_u|, \,\, \mathbf{e}_2=\mathbf{x}_v/|\mathbf{x}_v|$$
as my adapted frame. From this I calculate the one forms $\theta_i = \mathbf{e}_i \cdot d\mathbf{x}$ and $w_{12} = \mathbf{e}_1\cdot d\mathbf{e}_2$.

I find $\theta_1 = du$ and $\theta_2 = dv$ thus $\theta_1 \wedge \theta_2= du \wedge dv$ which gives the area form. Upon integrating over $u,v$ this is given by:

$$\int_{\mathbf{x}(D)}\theta_1 \wedge \theta_2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}dvdu= \infty$$

Then by the structure equations and Gauss equation I find that the $K=-1/\cosh^2(u)$. But now I struggle; I want to write something like:

$$\int_{\mathbf{x}(D)} K = \int_{D} K(\mathbf{x}(u,v))\theta_1 \wedge \theta_2$$

but $K(\mathbf{x}(u,v))$ makes no sense. I have only seen integrals of this form when $K$ is a constant or when it is easy to project some platonic solid onto the surface and use the Gauss-Bonnet but in this instance I feel a bit lost.

Comment: One way to approach this that might make things easier is to first bound $u$ by $-x \leq u \leq x$.  Then apply Gauss-Bonnet to this bounded surface to find $\iint_{M_x} K dA$, then take the limit of the result as $x \rightarrow \infty$.  This has simplified things for me in the past, but it may or may not work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral $\int_{\mathbf{x}(D)}K$ is given by $\int_DK(u,v)\theta_1 \wedge \theta_2$. In this case:

$$\int_DK(u,v)\theta_1 \wedge \theta_2 = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty-1/\cosh^2(u)dudv = \int_0^{2\pi}-2 =-4 \pi$$